# In C#, authenticate EWS and POP3 with a local user/machine certificate store?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, pop3

Considering the basic auth deprecation, is it possible to authenticate to EWS and POP3 from a C# application using a local machine or user certificate store?

Answer (score 0):

EWS supports the Client_Credentials flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow so you can use either a Client Secret of Certificate.

POP3,IMAP and SMTP while they do support OAuth don't support the Client_Credentials flow so you always need to use a credential for that.